# Real life importance of product topology on an arbitrary product of topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, numerical-methods

As a student in numerical analysis, I can see the analytical relevance of product topology on a finite product of topological spaces. Specifically, in convergence analysis, we may have to deal with finite dimensional vector spaces as domains and co-domains for our discretization operator. Nevertheless, I am an aspirant to know the real life importance of product topology (utilizing projection maps to construct sub-base) on arbitrary products (like $\Bbb R^\omega$).

Can we connect such spaces with function spaces which are again inevitable real life stuffs.

Comment: Infinite spaces and functions on them, or from them, arise naturally (e.g. consider sequences, or dual spaces: any function can be viewed as an element of a product space, and this is a key step in the proof of Alaoglu’s theorem!)

Comment: What is "real life importance"?`Do you mean mathematical life?